# Select element from a dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, joomla

I want to test an application in Joomla.
I have a dropdown with this code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label">
        <label id="jform_category-lbl" for="jform_category" class="required">
            Categoria<span class="star">&#160;*</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="jform_category" name="jform[category]" class="required" required aria-required="true">
            <option value="9">stanza singola</option>
            <option value="10">stanza doppia</option>
            <option value="11">posto letto</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Java for testing the site.
How can I select from the dropdown the "stanza doppia" option?

Comment: Creating `Select` object will be help, which mentioned in the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried on the above website mentioned by you and it worked for me. 
Actually you need to use **custom xpath** to pick the values from the drop-down and store it in a list. Then click the value you want.

**Sometime Select() doesn't works, you can use this workaround for selecting the values in drop down.**

Here is the working code for the same.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SelectDropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://bachecalloggi.listedisinistra.org/index.php/annunci");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Ricerca Avanzata')]")).click();
        select1(driver);
    }

        public static void select1(WebDriver driver) {
                  //Clicking on the Element to open the dropdown. 
                  WebElement clickme = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_energy_class_chzn']/a/span"));
                  clickme.click();
                  //Sometime need to wait, as it take some time to load the values in dropdown.
                  //Thread.sleep(3000);

                  //Picking all the value from Dropdown. Use Custom Xpath for this.
                  List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_energy_class_chzn']//*[@class='chzn-results']/li"));

                  for (int i=0; i<options.size(); i++){
                   if (options.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                    options.get(i).click();
                   }
                  }         

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class

```
WebElement elemnet = driver.findElement(By.id("jform_category"));
Select select = new Select(elemnet);
//By value
select.selectByValue("10");

//By index
select.selectByIndex(2);

//By text
select.selectByVisibleText("stanza doppia");
```

Comment: I try but it dowsn't work :(
I have the same problem on a public page: http://bachecalloggi.listedisinistra.org/index.php/annunci

this is the code:
`
  public void testFilterAds() throws Exception {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Ricerca Avanzata')]")).click();
 
 WebElement elemnet = driver.findElement(By.id("filter_energy_class"));
    Select select = new Select(elemnet);
    //By value
    select.selectByValue("b");

    //By index
    select.selectByIndex(2);

    //By text
    select.selectByVisibleText("B");
 
    Thread.sleep(500000);
    
  }`

Comment: nothing is selected :(

Comment: You are not using the same code I am

Comment: can you post a completa class to select B in dropdown of filter_energy_class on page http://bachecalloggi.listedisinistra.org/index.php/annunci ? please